# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

Este es el codigo

```
   def percentage (part, whole):
    return 100*float(part)/float(whole)

keyword= input("please enter keyword or hashtag to search: ")
noOfTweet= int(input("Please enter how many tweets to analyze: "))

tweets= tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=keyword). items(noOfTweet)
positive=0
negative=0
neutral=0
polarity=0
tweet_list= []
neutral_list= []
negative_list= []
positive_list= []

for tweet in tweets:
    #print(tweet.text)
    tweet_list.append(tweet.text)
    analysis= TextBlob(tweet.text)
    score= SentimentIntensityAnalyzer().polarity_scores(tweet.text)
    neg= score['neg']
    neu= score['neu']
    pos= score['pos']
    comp= score['compound']
    polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity
    
    if neg > pos:
        negative_list.append(tweet.text)
        negative += 1
    
    elif pos > neg:
        positive_list.append(tweet.text)
        positive += 1
    
    elif pos == neg:
         neutral_list.append(tweet.text)
         neutral += 1
    
    positive= percentage (positive, noOfTweet)
    negative= percentage (negative, noOfTweet)
    neutral= percentage (neutral, noOfTweet)
    polarity= percentage (polarity, noOfTweet)
    positive= format(positive, '.1f')
    negaitve= format(negative, '.1f')
    neutral= format(neutral, '.1f') `
```

Este el error y no encuentro como corregirlo

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-87f41efd0a68> in <module>
    38     elif pos == neg:
    39          neutral_list.append(tweet.text)
---> 40          neutral += 1
    41 
    42     positive= percentage (positive, noOfTweet)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer sentiment analysis de Twitter, por lo que estoy probano este codigo que encontre en un sitio de data analysis.

- He seguido todos los pasos pero me da el error de TypeError que ya menciono.
- He intentado convertir una parte de la línea con error a str o a int y en ninguno de los dos casos ha funcionado o no lo he hecho correctamente.
- He estado trabajando en Jupiter Notebook y en Spyder, pero en los dos me da el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es ocupar la misma variable `neutral` para dos fines distintos.

Primero usas `neutral` como contador:

```
neutral = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    ...
    elif pos == neg:
         neutral_list.append(tweet.text)
         neutral += 1
```

y luego reemplazas el valor con un string:

```
neutral = format(neutral, '.1f')
```

con lo que en la siguiente iteración intentaras sumarle 1 a un string, que Python interpretara como concatenación.
**Solución**

Ocupa una variable distinta para el valor formateado. Por ejemplo,

```
s_neutral = format(neutral, '.1f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se te fue una tilde invertida al final de la última linea

```
neutral= format(neutral, '.1f') #`
```

Inténtalo nuevamente sin la tilde